# How can i create the following route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails beginner, so please don't bite. I've taken over the maintenance/development of a rails an app, but still learning the ropes

I'd like to generate the following route :

> /events/1/Project/2/Pledge

Where 1 is the `eventId` and 2 is the `Project Id`.

I have a project controller and and events controller. The pledge action is on the Project controller

EDIT: In answer to @wacko's comment below.

a)Ignore the casing and pluralization of the url i asked for (I realise that invalidates the original question somewhat...)

An event has multiple projects, The pledge action will take the user to a page where they can enter multiple pledges for a particular project.

Perhaps instead the Pledge action should be on the Events Controller instead?

and the URL something like 'events/1/pledge/2' (Where 2 is the projectId)

Comment: Can you describe the relationship between the models? Just to confirm... does `events` go in plural, `Project` and `Pledge` in singular and with a capital letter? I would expect an url like `/events/1/projects/2/pledge` (or .../pledges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a nested resource, that is to say that there is a parent child relationship between two resources.

```
resource :events do
  resource :projects do
    get :pledge, :on => :member
  end
end
```

For this to work, your models would look something like this

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

And

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Comment: Would the fact that the event relationship is  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects & the project relationship is has_and_belongs_to_many :events change any of your advice?

Comment: Many to many relationships should work with this routing logic

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
get '/events/:event_id/projects/:id/pledge' => 'projects#pledge'
```

In your controller action you can get the event_id and project_id from the params hash as `params[:event_id]` and `params[:id]` respectively

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :events do
  resources :projects do
    member do
      get :pledge
    end
  end
end
```

You can change `get` to the `http` method you want.
You can use `collections` if you need a route like `/events/1/projects/pledge`

```
collection do
  get :pledge
end
```

run `rake routes` from the project root folder to see a list of routes generated

Comment: You could also use `:on` to eliminate the last block: `get :pledge, on: :member`

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :events do
  resource :projects do
    resources :pledge
  end
end
```

this will give you the ability to set the scope in your controllers and have access to all 7 REST verbs

Answer (score 1):

jsut use this way

```
resources :events do
 resource :projects do
   get '/pledge'
 end
end
```